# How to fill data in the table columns and rows dynamically

Tags: angular, html-table

I get array of strings from api and need to show them in table (word1, word2, word3 etc). I don't know exactly how much it will be. The number of columns in table should be 5 and the number of rows depends on this array.

```
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 1</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 2</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 3</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 4</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 5</a></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 6</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 7</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 8</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 9</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#">Cell 9</a></th>
                    </tr>
```

If there 20 items -should be 4 rows. I have no idea how to start new row.
The examples are with filling by rows like below show how to fill by rows

```
  <tr *ngFor="let tablerows of data">
                      <td>
                      {{tablerows.row_id}}
                      </td>
                      <td>{{tablerows.number}}</td>
                      <td >{{tablerows.employee_name}}</td>
                      <td >{{tablerows.manager_name}}
                      </td>
                    </tr>
```

IS it possible to do it by angular? Or maybe should I create some arrays in component?

Comment: are you using material ?

Comment: @programoholic bootstrap

Comment: can you post sample of  row json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably pretty bad, but since it's also bad having an array of strings to manipulate in that way instead of an array of objects as needed, here goes:

in the component, split your array in subarrays of length 5 and push them in a new array, like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
    this.foo.push(i);
 }

 for(let x=0; x<this.foo.length; i+5){
  this.bar.push(this.foo.splice(x,x+5));
 }

}
```

I used a numeric array just to show. In the html, you can now ignore foo and only work on bar, like this:

```
  <table style="border:1px solid">          
      <tr *ngFor="let qwe of bar" style="border:1px solid">
        <td *ngFor="let asd of qwe" style="border:1px solid"> {{asd}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

I understand this isn't exactly your case, but I think you can work out your logic from here (probably you can't cycle on the s, I'd guess, since you have specific keys to access, but still :) )

Comment: thank you very much, I can succeed in it now. You mentioned that it is better to have an array of objects, I can get it also.What will be the difference in this case?

Comment: In my example you just go sequentially, with number ids. If you received an array of objects, with key-value pairs, you could access them in any order and the code would be more readable. Also you wouldn't need to transform manually "foo" into "bar" in the component, you would have "bar" already, directly from the API.